# String Compare in Oracle Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, procedure

Trying to compare two string. one from IN parameter(myname) and another is Hard coded('abcd').

```
(myname IN  VARCHAR2)
-- myname will be set to 'abcd' when calling this procedure
DECLARE
name VARCHAR2(10):=myname;
IF(name='abcd') THEN
--update something in database
END IF;
```

Actual code is given below. idegreeName is set to 'HONS'. if I remove if block then my procedure works fine. but I need IF block to execute update query.

```
// Calling in JAVA
stmt = (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall("{ call receiveAdmission2(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)  }");
// my procedure
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NU_DB.receiveAdmission2 (

   iAdmissionRoll          IN  VARCHARARRAY,
   iUserId                 IN  VARCHAR2,
   iCollegeCode            IN  VARCHAR2,
   isessionId              IN  VARCHAR2,
   isubjectId              IN  VARCHAR2,
   iMeritType              IN  VARCHAR2,
   iStatus                 IN  VARCHAR2,
   iXforward               IN  VARCHAR2,
   iVia                    IN  VARCHAR2,
   iRemoteAddress          IN  VARCHAR2,

   oResponseCode           OUT NUMBER,
   oResponseMessage        OUT VARCHAR2,
   oResponse               OUT VARCHAR2,

   idegreeName              IN  VARCHAR2

)
IS

 tErrorCode   VARCHAR2(20);
 tErrorMsg    VARCHAR2(400);
 tResponse    VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN

    oResponse:='';
    DECLARE
    str1  VARCHAR2(10):=idegreeName;

    Begin

        FOR i IN 1 .. iAdmissionRoll.COUNT
        LOOP


           IF(str1='HONS') THEN

           UPDATE nu_hons_result set STATUS=iStatus where ADMISSION_ROLL=iAdmissionRoll(i) and  MERIT_TYPE=iMeritType and COLLEGE_CODE=iCollegeCode and  SUBJECT_ID=isubjectId and STATUS='Student Requested';

           END IF;

         if (sql%rowcount > 0) then
             tResponse := 'Successfully approved.';

             if(iMeritType<>5) then

             UPDATE nu_college_subject_map set AVAILABLE_SEAT=AVAILABLE_SEAT-1 where SESSION_ID=isessionId and COLLEGE_CODE=iCollegeCode and  SUBJECT_ID=isubjectId;

             end if;


            insert into NU_HONS_SUBJECT_ADMISSION (ADMISSION_ROLL,SESSION_ID,COLLEGE_CODE,SUBJECT_ID,APPROVED_BY,APPROVED_ON) 
                values(iAdmissionRoll(i),isessionId,iCollegeCode,isubjectId,iUserId,sysdate);

            insert into nu_log_admission values (iAdmissionRoll(i),isessionId,iCollegeCode,iMeritType,iStatus,sysdate,isubjectId);

           else
             tResponse := 'Failed to approve.'||idegreeName; 
          end if;  

         oResponse := oResponse || tResponse || '###';


        END LOOP;

     EXCEPTION WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        tErrorCode:=SQLCODE;
        tErrorMsg:=SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 400);
        oResponseCode := 1;
        oResponseMessage :=tErrorMsg;
        ROLLBACK;
        Return;
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        tErrorCode:=SQLCODE;
        tErrorMsg:=SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 400);
        oResponseCode := 2;
        oResponseMessage :=tErrorMsg;
        ROLLBACK;
        Return;

    End;

END receiveAdmission2;
/
```

Problem is IF block is not executing.

Comment: Apparently myname is not equal to 'abcd'. Can you paste a complete example? I mean the procedure and how you are calling it

Comment: I just edited my question with complete code.

Comment: 1. How do you know that the IF block is not executing.

Comment: 2. Are you sure you're passing HONS as idegreeName?

Comment: That was 'hons'. Thanks Dear.

Answer (score 0):

Youre code works like expected. I added logging for test purposes. Show how you call the code or add logging for the parameters and work from there

```
DECLARE name VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN

name := 'abcd';

IF ( name = 'abcd')  THEN
 dbms_output.put_line('equal');
ELSE 
 dbms_output.put_line('NOT equal');
END IF;

END;
```

Comment: I just edited my question. String from IN parameter is needed.

Comment: best practice is to put OUT parameters as last.